# NotFoundHttpException on live server

Tags: php, laravel, server

I deployed my laravel project on cPanel and all works except one thing: when I am logged in and if I click create article button then I should see a create article page, but I got `NotFoundHttpException` error. On my local computer with xampp this function works and I do not know why is that. Can anyone help me, please?
This is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: When you get the NotFoundHttpException, the URL is correct? It may be some error on the link generation

Comment: Yes, when I click article button, I will be /admin/create_articles and my route is:  Route::get('/admin/create_articles', 'ArticlesController@create');
This works on xampp, but it is not ok on live server.

Comment: Is your controller name starts with Capital letter ?

Comment: I am stupid...I changed my route to this: Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () { and now it show my creating article page when I am logged in.